# Finding accumulation points and isolation points for a given set

Tags: real-analysis, rational-numbers

I am trying to find $ S' $ for function S:{ r $\in Q$ , $ 0<r\le\sqrt2$ }

Now I believe that $S'={\{0,\sqrt2\}}$ and isolation point is ${\{1}\}$
Now my understanding for this answer is that since $\sqrt2\ $is a irrational number it could never be a part of $S$, also for isolation any $x\in S$ and $x\notin S'$ is isolation. Is this the correct approach

Comment: Q usually means the rational numbers. It looks like perhaps you are thinking of integers? Do you mean isolated point? I have not heard of isolation point. Lastly, S seems to be a set, not a function. Why do you think 1 is isolated? You should justify the claim.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4780457/27978

Comment: If $Q$ means rational numbers, then $S'=[0,\sqrt2]$ and there is no isolated point, this is because rational numbers are dense in real numbers, you could check out [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1263958/how-do-you-prove-the-set-of-accumulation-points-of-q-is-r) for some explanations

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding accumulation points and isolation points for a given set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780457/finding-accumulation-points-and-isolation-points-for-a-given-set)

Comment: I do not understand the link takes me back to my own question @blargoner

Comment: From what I understand accumulation point is something a value in set is approaching towards but never really reaching it. Since $\sqrt2$ is in set but not reachable as r$\in Q$ so $S'={0, \sqrt2 }$

Comment: @Govt_employee It's quite a mystery indeed.

Comment: Somehow I posted 2 same questions I did not understand but I deleted that question since it was not answered